# Filter issues resolved more than 6 weeks ago on a YouTrack board

Tags: youtrack

We are using a Kanban board in YouTrack, as Kanban has no sprints the “Complete” column keeps on piling up with completed tasks. To solve this we want to create a filter that would filter all tasks that were resolved more than 6 weeks ago. I could not find a way to accomplish that. Could this be done? If yes how?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best option will be to use `resolved date: -Older` query. This will display all issues resolved in the last two months (refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Search-and-Command-Attributes.html#Date-and-Period-Values). 
I'm afraid there is no way to create a similar filter for 6 weeks (except for specifying the exact date and updating it every day, like `resolved date: -1970-01-01 .. 2019-03-01`).
Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following filter to achieve this:

```
resolved date: {minus 2w} .. Today
```

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/server/search-and-command-attributes.html#custom-date-parameters for more details.